# How to I remove file from git repository but NOT have it removed from post_receive target?

Tags: git

I'm very new to this git thing. I'm using it simply (yeah right) to maintain my own website files between my local pc and remote webserver.

There are some files, such as settings and .htaccess files, that I want on the server to be left alone after a push.  Now... some of them I thought ahead and put into the .gitignore file at the start of this and they are fine.  But others that I've discovered since... I add them to the .gitignore now and they still get clobbered on a push!  They are ignored on the local side for sure.  I *think* what is happening is the files are not getting transfered to the remove repo, but the copy already in the remote repo is getting post_received processed over to the destination and *poof*.

So I tried "remove" but once I pushed, it removed the file from the final destination too!  Not at all what I want!

So how can I get it to a) ignore the file on the destination end and b) remove it from the remote repo and c) still have my local copy untouched?

Answer (score 0):

Gitignore is the correct way to do it. You should be fine if you now just restore/generate the files again on the destination computer. The remove made git delete the files.

Answer (score 0):

The .gitignore should ignore all the files specified in it. However, you will probably need to maintain a .gitignore on the destination side as well.

If you want to remove the file from the repo but still have the local copy use `git rm --cached "filename"`. This removes the file from the repo leaving the file untouched on your local system.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this.

First, it's the transition from "in the checkout" to "not in the checkout" that git interprets as a deletion from the checkout (and hence the checked-out worktree) -- reasonable enough, but when you're using it for deployment as here it's not always what you want.  No matter -- after checkout removes it, git's no longer tracking it and you can put it back.  That'll work until you check out an older branch that still has it,

Second, you could leave it tracked but put a repo-local override that tells git not to overwrite it in the worktree or in the repo.  Git has "filters" that you can use to sanitize content on the way in to and out of the repo, and it's easy to feed it one that pins content at whatever's there already:

```
git config filter.pin-content.smudge 'cat %f 2>&-       || cat'
git config filter.pin-content.clean  'git show :%f 2>&- || cat'

echo path/to/file filter=pin-content >>.git/info/attributes
```

The "smudge" direction is for dirtying content up for work use, "clean" is for making the pristine platonic ideal content in your repo.

For both these ways, the transition from in-the-checkout to not-in-the-checkout will be interpreted as a deletion.

There's a perfectly honorable way to work around that, involving `git read-tree` to update the index and then doing your own postprocessing to preserve the worktree content you want, but if others are going to be using or maintaining this it's worth considering how unpopular forcing people to learn the innards might be.  The docs for read-tree are particularly (and imo unnecessrily) intimidating, so it's a real concern.

Comment: First... totally appreciate your time.  There's some irony (from my point of view) when reading that last sentence in relation to your answer :)  To me... I've read your answer about 10 times now and I'm rubbing my eyes and wondering what hit me.  Put another way... "huh?"

Comment: for the first -- when you remove the file from your commit and then check out that commit, git sees the removal and removes it from the worktree ... but only the once. When you check out the next commit after that, the file is untracked in the current and untracked in the new, so git leaves it alone in the worktree.  for the rest, it'll make more sense when you're farther into git, but the basics are more important now so ignore the rest.